# Curl command in shell script returning error {"Error":"bpapigw-300 Cannot authorize access to resource"

Tags: shell, curl, command-line, scripting, using

I am trying to execute curl using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"adminpw", "tenant":"master"}' https://localhost/tron/api/v1/tokens > /tmp/token.data

grep -Po '{\"token\":\"\K[^ ]...................' /tmp/token.data > /tmp/token

tokendetails=`cat /tmp/token`
for token in $tokendetails
do
  TOKEN=`echo $token`
done
userdetails=`cat /tmp/curloutput.txt | sed 's/{"clientInactivityTime"/\n{"clientInactivityTime"/g' | sed 's/\(.*\).\("firstName":[^,]*\)\(.*\)\("lastName":[^,]*\)\(.*\)\("email":[^,]*\)\(.*\)\("username":[^,]*\)\(.*\)/\2,\4,\6,\8/g' | grep username`

for user in $userdetails
do
  firstName=`echo $user | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep firstName | sed 's/.*:"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'`
  lastName=`echo $user | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep lastName | sed 's/.*:"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'`
  email=`echo $user | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep email | sed 's/.*:"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'`
  username=`echo $user | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep username | sed 's/.*:"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'`


curl -k -X POST "https://haxsne09/tron/api/v1/users" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer =${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "first_name=${firstName}\&last_name=${lastName}\&email=${email}\&password=Tata123^\&username=${username}\&is_active=true"



echo $RESPONSE
done
```

I am getting ths error:

```
{"Error":"bpapigw-300 Cannot authorize access to resource: Could not authorize path for user identifier: Failed to get Roles for identifier: REST operation  failed 0 times: '[GET /api/v1/current-user][401] currentUserListUnauthorized  \u0026{Detail:Invalid token}'. This user is unauthenticated?"}
```

Do I need to add any syntax before executing `curl -k -X POST`?

Comment: Please provide us with a sample `/tmp/token.data` file

Comment: We would also need to see what `/tmp/curloutput.txt` looks like

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that `-H "Authorization: Bearer =${TOKEN}"` contains an `=` sign which shouldn't be there...
It should be: `-H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"`

More, in a command you use `/tmp/curloutput.txt` file, which is never created by your script...

Comment: Thanks @MarcoS
Whenever I use an echo command I was getting the username in the output.
But when I use the curl command directly without echo command it gives me the output as "username":[Enter a valid username]

Comment: Curl returns what your server at `https://localhost/tron/api/v1/tokens` answers... So you should investigate on that service and which username it is expecting... :-)

Comment: Hello @MarcoS something which I wanted to highlight that whenever I echo the curl command I get an output in which all the parameters are fetched like username, password, token etc. But when I directly execute the command on the server it  gives the error. 
I think you must be having an answer as to what to use exactly with in the shell script to use the curl command so that the command get executed.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "whenever I echo the curl command"? Can yo make a clear example of the two cases?

Answer (score 0):

The `Authorization` header you are using is not working. Maybe the syntax is not `Bearer =aAbBcCdDeEfF0123456` but something else for the server running on `haxsne09`, maybe without the `=` like @MarcoS suggests.
Alternatively, your grep command may be returning one too many characters (a rogue quote maybe).

I rewrote your code below to be more readable. You will notice that I:

- Changed your matching groups in `sed` to capture only the needed parts and put them in variables using `read`. I also used the `-E` flag to avoid having to use `\(` and `\)`
- Removed the useless `for` loops
- Quoted all variable expansions properly
- Added some line breaks for readability
- Removed some temporary files and associated useless uses of cat

Here is the updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -k -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d \
  '{"username":"admin","password":"adminpw", "tenant":"master"}' \ 
  https://localhost/tron/api/v1/tokens > /tmp/token.data

token=$(grep -Po '{"token":"\K[^ ]...................' /tmp/token.data)

IFS=, read -r firstName lastName email username < <(
  </tmp/curloutput.txt sed 's/{"clientInactivityTime"/\n&/' |
  sed -nE 's/.*."firstName":"([^"]*)".*"lastName":"([^"]*)").*"email":"([^"]*).*"username":"([^"]*)".*/\1,\2,\3,\4/p'
)

curl -k -X POST 'https://haxsne09/tron/api/v1/users' -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d \
  "first_name=$firstName&last_name=$lastName&email=$email&password=Tata123^&username=$username&is_active=true"

echo
```

Comment: `/tmp/curloutput.txt: No such file or directory` ... :-(

Comment: See my comments the question -- I'm assuming the file exists since his code did not produce it

Comment: I see... Sorry, didn't realise that. The question is uncomplete... We should vote to close it, probably...